# Minimum Cost Maximum Flow Algorithm with restrictions

Tags: algorithm, optimization, graph-theory

I have met a real life problem and need to solve the following.
In 2D plane, there are two types of points.
The first type stands for the server.
The second type stands for the client.
Every client needs exactly one server each.
And the requirement is to minimize the sum of distances between every client-server connections.

So I thought I can solve this problem by constructing a bipatite graph and solve minimum-cost-maximum-flow.
But I can't because of the restriction.
The restriction is that every server must have the same number of clients.
If there exists remainders, the difference between numbers must not exceed 1.
So I decided to give flow-restrictions on edges to server.
Flow(fi) must be in interval [n_client / n_server, n_client / n_server + 1].
But still I can't find the solution.

What algorithm should I use and how can I solve this problem.
The maximum number of servers is 500.
But the max number of clients can reach 10^5.
However, it'll be OK if the time-complexity of algorithm gets more than 1 hour.

Comment: It would be interesting to know if this algorithm needs to be run once, or you'd have to dynamically compute which client goes to which server (like on a website, you don't know who is going to visit in advance)

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually, the problem could be formulated as an integer linear programming problem, but that would be impractical in view of the very large size of the problem (500 servers and 100,000 clients). I have included that formulation below, however, for general interest.

If one requirement can be relaxed, the problem can be formulated as a type of linear programming problem called the [transportation problem](https://www.imsl.com/blog/solving-transportation-problem#:%7E:text=Unlike%20many%20LP%20problems%2C%20the,or%20the%20Stepping%20Stone%20Method.), for which specialized algorithms are available that produce optimal solutions for very large problems reasonably quickly.

**Linear programming transportation problem**

Rather than requiring, for each pair of servers, that the difference between the numbers of clients served by each server be limited in some faction, the user would be required to specify the number of clients to be served by each server, such that those numbers summed over all servers would equal the number of clients.

This procedure reduces the problem to the well-known *transporation problem*. These problems can be solved with a general-purpose linear programming solver or with specialized algorithms. One could code a specialized algorithm, or call a commercial or public-domain solver library from one's code, or use a stand-alone solver.

*Known constants*

- d<sub>ij</sub> equals distance between client i and by server j
- n<sub>j</sub> equals number of clients to be served by server j

*Variables*

- x<sub>ij</sub> equals 1 if client i is assigned to server j; else equals 0

*Formulation*

min Σ<sub>i</sub>Σ<sub>j</sub>d<sub>ij</sub>x<sub>ij</sub>

subject to:

Σ<sub>j</sub>x<sub>ij</sub> = 1 for each client i

Σ<sub>i</sub>x<sub>ij</sub> = n<sub>j</sub> for each server j

0 <= x<sub>ij</sub> <= 1 for all clients i and servers j

Even though the formulation permits the variables to be assigned values between 0 and 1 (e.g., 0.5), algorithms for the assignment problem have the property that they produce an optimal solution for which all variables are assigned integer values (0 or 1).

After solving the problem, changes could be made to the numbers of clients served by each server, after which the problem could be re-solved to see how the optimal value (total distance) changes. Iterative improvements could be made with this trial-and-error procedure.

Further efficiencies might be achieved in various ways. For example,  if:

- if could be assumed that a group of `n` clients would be served by the same server, in which case the group of clients would be replaced by a single client whose distance to each server would be `n` times the actual distance; and
- the problem could be decomposed into independent sub-problems by creating disjoint geographical areas such that clients within each area must be served by servers within the same area.

**Integer linear optimization problem**

If there are `c` clients and `s` servers between `f = c/s` (integer division) and `f+1` clients can be assigned to each server.

Note below that the the variables, objective function (to be minimized) and one of the constraints are the same as in the assignment problem.

*Formulation*

min Σ<sub>i</sub>Σ<sub>j</sub>d<sub>ij</sub>x<sub>ij</sub>

subject to:

Σ<sub>j</sub>x<sub>ij</sub> = 1 for each client i

Σ<sub>i</sub>x<sub>ij</sub> - f >= 0 for each server j

Σ<sub>i</sub>x<sub>ij</sub> - f <= 1 for each server j

x<sub>ij</sub> = 0 or 1 for all clients i and servers j

Comment: Thank you very much about your professional response.
I find this very helpful for me.

Comment: Very pretty answer.  As usual, applying linear programming leads to an absurd amount of complexity.  Almost always, it is simpler and more flexible to solve the problem directly.

Comment: @Roman  This is not a 'professional' answer.  It is an academic answer, suitable for getting top marks in a computer science course.  Out here in the real world this approach will bog you down in complexity.

Comment: I also think this would be slow. MIP is NP-hard, and there could be 500*10^5 variables, which if I had to guess would go over the 1-hour mark even with the solvers (depends of course on the computational power)

Comment: @me9hanics, I missed the numbers of servers and clients in the statement of the problem. With that number of variables I would share your skepticism. Not only are the numbers of variable large, but the numbers of constraints as well (2*500 + 10^5). Solution times would likely be much greater than an hour, possibly weeks, possible years, one rarely can tell in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple round robin problem.

The algorithm goes like this:

```
LOOP until stop
Loop over servers
  SET closest = NULL
  SET shortest = INFINITY
  Loop over clients 
     IF client has server
         CONTINUE
     SET dist = distance from client to server
     IF dist < shortest
       SET closest = client
       SET shortest = dist
  ENDLOOP over clients
  IF closest == NULL
       STOP
  Connect closest client to server
ENDLOOP over servers
ENDLOOP until stop
```

Here is some C++ code to implement this

```
while( true )
   {
        // loop over servers
        for( auto s : theDataStore.theServers )
        {
            cClient* closest = 0;
            double shortest = DBL_MAX;

            // loop over clients
            for( auto c : theDataStore.theClients )
            {
                // client already connected to server
                if( c->hasServer() )
                    continue;
                
                // check for closest client so far
                double dist2 = c->dist2( *s );
                if( dist2 < shortest ) {
                    shortest = dist2;
                    closest = c;
                }
            }

            // check if all clients connected to a server
            if( ! closest ) {

                // done, reprt results
                std::cout << "Clients per server: ";
                for( auto sc : theDataStore.theServers )
                    std::cout << sc->clientCount() << " ";
                std::cout << "\n";
                return;
            }

            // connect client to server
            closest->Server( s );
            
        }
   }
```

Output is:

```
3 servers, 10 clients
Clients per server: 4 3 3
```

Complete application code at https://github.com/JamesBremner/so78008650

Comment: Thank you! But A Problem still exists.

Comment: What is an A problem?

Comment: Imagine there are 10 clients and 3 servers.
As a result, 3 servers must have the following numbers [4, 3, 3]. of connections.
But the above method can lead to [4, 4, 2] which is not true.

Comment: I do not think so.  Say we have reached [2,2,2].  Then we get [3,2,2], then [3,3,2] then [3,3,3] and at last [4,3,3] Now we must stop because all clients are served.

Comment: Is your algorithm guaranteed to produce an optimal solution, or does it intend to produce a "good" solution?

Comment: I mean an optimal solution.

Comment: This is not optimal on minimizing distances, since it is a [greedy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm) algorithm. It could be that we pick server _A_ for client _1_, instead of server _B_ which way the distance sum would grow by let's say, 1 unit more (client _1_ lives almost in the middle of the two servers). Then comes client _2_, lives much closer to server _A_ than _B_, but has to be assigned to _B_ because client _1_ "took the space". This would give a quite inconvenient experience which can be improved e.g. by looping in some specific order that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could actually get a **very nearly optimal** solution (which can be improved to be optimal easily but that would be slow) with a bipartite graph minimum cost maximum flow:

The key idea is that instead of having nodes of the servers, you have a node for each "place on servers", assigned to each server. Basically you would have the number of clients amount of nodes on one side, and almost the same amount on the other side. I will explain with numbers:

Let's say, you have *15* servers, and *1000* clients. Then according to the restriction, every server will have either *1000//15=66*, or *67* clients, only *10* servers will have *67* clients. Create a bipartite graph, where there is a node on one side for each client, and on the other, there are *15*66=990* nodes, representing places on each server. Every client is connected to every place node, and the edge weights are defined as the distances to the representative server: the first batch of 66 nodes have edge weights equal to the distances to server 1, the second batch is for distances to server 2, and so on...

Then you run a *minimum cost maximum flow* algorithm. You'll get the smallest distance, assigning 990 clients to 990 places, only 10 clients are left out, they will take up the 67th place on 10 servers. To do that, you can just create a bipartite graph again, 10 clients, 15 servers, and run min cost max flow again.

For your case, we do the same, just with `k=500` servers, `n` ~ 10<sup>5</sup> clients, assigning firstly `floor(n/k)` people to each server with MCMF, then assign the remaining `n - k*math.floor(n/k)` to a server too.

(The amount of nodes needed for this algorithm can be computed in the beginning, assuming that we know at the time of running the algorithm how many clients there will be, which is what I understood from the post.)

Comment: I have a couple of questions about your first sentence. Firstly, what is you basis for the claim, "You could actually get a very nearly optimal solution..."? Can you, for example, produce a bound on the maximum difference between what you get and the value of an optimal solution? Secondly, you state "...which can be improved to be optimal easily...". I do not understand what form those changes would take. I would think the requirements concerning the maximum difference between the numbers of clients served between each pair of servers would throw a wrench into the works.

Comment: The changes are not described because they would make the algorithm slow and unusable, at least the ones I came up with in my head. Maybe one fast optimal solutions may exist too, but I couldn't exclude this being an NP-hard problem. Such a change could be (in the example) going through all 990 clients - 10 clients pairs and checking if any improvements can be made between the pairs. I don't think it is worth the computation.

Comment: There is no theoretical lower limit between this solution's "cost" and the optimal value assuming arbitrarily large differences in distances.

But the problem is much more bounded (edge weights are geographical distances, etc.) and knowing the limitations one could bound the WC/average error very well. Firstly, there is no error if *k|n*. 

If you have 100000 players, and you find the lowest distance 99501-client matching for the first 99501 nodes, the same for 499 remaining ones, what is the chance that the sum of the two is marginally larger than the lowest cost 10^5 matching?